# Custom Git hunk header for Apex (on GitHub)?

Tags: apex, visualforce, git, github, diff

In every Git diff there's this thing called a *hunk header* at the beginning of the diff section that looks like this:

```
@@ -23,12 +23,10 @@ public with sharing class MyClass {
```

This is nice but not very helpful as it never shows the actual "section" in the code - it always shows the class name rather than the method name. So I heard that you can configure this so you get a decent *hunk header* for Apex, similar to C/C++/C#/Java (etc.). So obviously this would be my first question - how to configure this to get this for Apex/Visualforce/etc. as well. But I have not checked for this yet since I'm not even sure this can be configured for GitHub pull requests or how does this work there? Any ideas? I'm a little bit clueless right now and not even sure if this is the right place to ask this question. If so, please hint me in the right direction.